# AJAX Form submission inside qtip2

Tags: jquery, qtip2

q:

How do I manipulate ajax requests (or just objects) for forms/html inside qtip declaration?

details:

Right now, I have a series of javascript datatables (populated via django backend) that contains various rows of information. Each row has a cell which contains a button for a qtip (qtip2) to popup with a simple form inside it with a textarea for notes and a submit button. This would seem very simple.

However, I am unable to figure out how to write/bind class handlers inside the class.

These are many of these tips that are dynamically generated (inside of a dynamic datatables column block), so I can't use hard selectors to access them. I am having no problems submitting these requests via a form action, but I'd really prefer them to be ajax.

```
$('.note_updater').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
            overwrite: false,
            content: {
              text: function(api) {
              return "<form><textarea type='text' name='notes' id='id_notes'>" + 
                      $(this).attr('qtip-content')  + "</textarea><br><input type='submit' value='Update' /></form>";

            },
            title: {
                text: function(api) { return $(this).attr('qtip-title') + ' notes'; },
                button: true
            }
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true
        },
        hide: 'unfocus',
        events: {
            render: function(event, api) {
            $('form', this).bind('submit', function(event) {
                window.alert('sanity')
            });

            }
        },
    })
});
```

In this example, when the submit is clicked, no 'sanity' alert appears.

Also, when I add objects such as a button inside the content {} block, I am unable to access these objects by class.

The qtips work fine, everything seems functional, but there is no response when buttons are clicked or sanity alerts when I try to catch submits.

There are no errors in the console.

This should be so simple, but it's driving me nuts! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the stupid-simple solution to this problem, although I abandoned qtips in favor or building a better ground up solution for my own problem.

However, the easiest thing to do would have been to do something like this

Simply include an anchor tag in the qtip that calls an onclick function.

```
<a onclick="doSomething()">Submit</a>

def doSomething(){ <do jquery magic here> }
```

D'oh! Simple.